# FastAPI api giving "str type expected" error

Tags: post, postman, fastapi, python-3.9

UPDATE: I downloaded the Uvicorn service and ran it again, then it worked

I have this code that returns the url of an amazon rds instance:

```
def get_host(instance_name):
    """This function receives the name of an RDS instance and returns its connection endpoint"""
    client = boto3.client('rds',
                        aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                        aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
                        region_name=AWS_DEFAULT_REGION)
    instance = client.describe_db_instances(DBInstanceIdentifier=instance_name)['DBInstances'][0]
    endpoint = instance['Endpoint']['Address']
    print(endpoint)
    return endpoint
```

and this api that calls it

```
@app.post("/host", tags=['host'])
def get_host_with_api(instance_name: str = Body()):
    return {"endpoint": get_host(instance_name)}.`
```

When I call the code directly using the function, like this: `get_host("instance10")` returns what I need, but when I use the api with postman I get this error:

```
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "body"
            ],
            "msg": "str type expected",
            "type": "type_error.str"
        }
    ]
}
```

when the api call is of type post, i am sending the parameter to it as

```
{
    "instance_name":"instance10"
}
```

in the body as raw data in json, why does it send me this error? I tried with another api that also receives strings and I sent them with the same format and it does receive them, what is wrong?

I tried with another api that also receives strings and I sent them with the same format and it does receive them, what is wrong?
I've tried calling only the function and the response is OK.